# Build error from Installing Apache Zeppelin

Tags: build, apache-zeppelin

I am at my wits end trying to get Apache Zeppelin running on my linux VM. I am following this tutorial:

http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.ca/2015/03/building-apache-zeppelin.html

I have done the following:

1. git clone to the machine
2. now trying to run 'mvn clean package'

I get the following error summary, I really need to get this running.

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Zeppelin .......................................... SUCCESS [16.124s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Interpreter ............................. SUCCESS [36.026s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Zengine ................................. SUCCESS [27.440s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark ................................... SUCCESS [53.438s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Markdown interpreter .................... SUCCESS [6.041s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Angular interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [7.397s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Shell interpreter ....................... SUCCESS [4.140s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Hive interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [1:09.114s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Tajo interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [15.153s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: web Application ......................... FAILURE [0.492s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Server .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:57.426s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 29 12:18:39 EDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 78M/266M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:install-node -and-npm (install node and npm) on project zeppelin-web: The plugin com.github.eirslett:fron tend-maven-plugin:0.0.23 requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the follow ing articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginIncompatibleExceptio n
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR] mvn <goals> -rf :zeppelin-web
```

I have tried contacting the apache incubator team through their email (users@zeppelin.incubator.apache.org) however the emails bounced back. Ill continue to bounce around looking for a solution.

Comment: Did you install Maven version 3.1.0?

Comment: I have the same issue, tried to sudo apt-get update then sudo apt-get --only-update install maven and it didnt update the version, i then downloaded the latest mvn version, exported the PATH and my mvn version is still 3.0.5

Comment: sudo apt-get remove maven then reloading .bash_profile got it to work

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Download , extract and install Maven3 (if not already installed) and set maven in PATH

export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin

even i have updated the PATH variable with latest maven. mvn -version shows 2.x

now manually updated the maven using update-alternatives.

bdalab@solai:/opt$ **sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/mvn mvn $MAVEN_HOME/bin/mvn 1**

bdalab@solai:/opt$ **sudo update-alternatives --config mvn**

Now, select a number referring to the recent maven3 installation, from the list of choices

Comment: For CDH, Download and extract Maven tar file. Extract Command -> tar -xvf <downloaded_maven_tar_filename>. Then, modify M2_HOME in /etc/profile, with the updated maven path. Lastly, execute "source" command or ". /etc/profile"

Answer (score 1):

I tried **mvn install -DskipTests**, with the following system configurations:
1) Java 7
2) Maven 3.3 - Download tar file. extract and update MAVEN_HOME in /etc/profile. Then run 'source' command 
3) Spark 0.9.0
4) CDH4 cluster

Build is successful for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can test your node and npm download url with wget first:
wget XXXnode-12.4.tar.gz
if this url can't download the file may be your network issuel

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might be missing the installation of nodejs, npm. Please install nodejs, npm.

```
sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
```

Comment: Thanks for your change, Kampai

Answer (score 0):

In my case below git config worked :

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Make sure Maven > v3.0 , npm , nodejs and bower should be installed.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue was that I was using maven 3.2.
Installed maven 3.3.3 and everything went fine, build again and everything went ok.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem with zeppelin and found the root cause to be a failure with 'bower install' command.

First you need to install nodejs

**yum install -y node**

then install bower

**npm install -g bower**

then install grunt

**npm install -g grunt**

run the following commands with a non-root user (i.e., create a zeppelin user)

**cd zeppelin-web**

**bower install** (takes some time to complete)

cd ..
mvn clean package -rf :zeppelin-web

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/NFLabs/zeppelin/issues/320

Switching github from git:// to https:// will do the trick.