# Zeppelin build failure

Tags: build, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to install zeppelin for spark1.0.0 and hadoop1.0.3.

Possible duplicate: [Build error from Installing Apache Zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950313/build-error-from-installing-apache-zeppelin)

Well, the above thread didn't help much. I have the exact same output as the above thread: the web application fails to compile.

The command I ran was 'mvn install -DskipTests -Dspark.version=1.0.0 -Dhadoop.version=1.0.3'

I have maven 3.0.4 / java 1.8 / npm 1.1.4

```
[INFO] Zeppelin .......................................... SUCCESS [2.880s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Interpreter ............................. SUCCESS [6.780s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Zengine ................................. SUCCESS [3.394s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark ................................... SUCCESS [31.284s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Markdown interpreter .................... SUCCESS [1.936s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Angular interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [1.916s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Shell interpreter ....................... SUCCESS [1.905s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Hive interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [2.226s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Tajo interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [2.061s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Flink ................................... SUCCESS [3.358s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: web Application ......................... FAILURE [0.215s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Server .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 58.228s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 16 11:50:03 KST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 47M/485M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project zeppelin-web: The plugin com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23 requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginIncompatibleException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :zeppelin-web
```

Yes, I did already switched from git:// to https:// and tried again and it did not work.

Comment: can you please help me with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855207/getting-error-while-building-the-zeppelin

Comment: I got same error and still do when following suggestsion to remove nodeJS, nvm, and npm.  Only solution was work around which is to install Zeppellin from binary.  Using CentOS 6.8.   Error:  "Failed to run task: 'yarn install --no-lockfile' failed. ... Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:yarn (yarn install) on project zeppelin-web"

Answer (score 3):

As the error message point out :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:install-node-and-npm 
(install node and npm) on project zeppelin-web: 
The plugin com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23 
requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]
```

You'll need to update your maven version from 3.0.4 to at least 3.1.0.

But you'll encounter another error : `zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'npm install --color=false' failed`

To correct that one, you'll need to run your `mvn` command as a sudoer or an administrator:

```
sudo mvn install -DskipTests -Dspark.version=1.0.0 -Dhadoop.version=1.0.3
```

Comment: Thanks. Updating Maven to 3.1 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I added the following elemets to .bowerrc file under ~/incubator-zeppelin-master/zeppelin-web.

"proxy" : "http://:",
"https-proxy" : "http://:"

After that, I tried to build again and it successfully completed without using sudo command.

Please refer to the follwing URL:
https://github.com/NFLabs/zeppelin/tree/master/zeppelin-web

Answer (score 0):

I tried **mvn install -DskipTests**, with the following system configurations:
1) Java 7
2) Maven 3.3
3) Spark 0.9.0
4) CDH4 cluster

Build is successful for me.

Comment: can you please help me with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855207/getting-error-while-building-the-zeppelin. I would really appreciate your help.