# Getting error while building the Apache Zeppelin

Tags: maven, build, cloudera-cdh, apache-zeppelin

I have my hadoop already setup with cloudera. I wanted to install zeppelin to connect with hive and build the UI for my queries. While building the zeppelin command with the following command:

```
sudo mvn clean package -Pspark-1.3 -Dspark.version=1.3.0 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0-cdh5.4.7 -Phadoop-2.6 -Pyarn -DskipTests
```

I get this error at the web-application module :

```
[ERROR] npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-71-generic
[ERROR] npm ERR! argv "/home/zeppelin/incubator-zeppelin/zeppelin-web/node/node" "/home/zeppelin/incubator-zeppelin/zeppelin-web/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
[ERROR] npm ERR! node v4.6.2
[ERROR] npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
[ERROR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[ERROR] npm ERR! zeppelin-web@0.0.0 build: `grunt build`
[ERROR] npm ERR! Exit status 3
[ERROR] npm ERR!
[ERROR] npm ERR! Failed at the zeppelin-web@0.0.0 build script 'grunt build'.
[ERROR] npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
[ERROR] npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the zeppelin-web package,
[ERROR] npm ERR! not with npm itself.
[ERROR] npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     grunt build
[ERROR] npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     npm bugs zeppelin-web
[ERROR] npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     npm owner ls zeppelin-web
[ERROR] npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     /home/zeppelin/incubator-zeppelin/zeppelin-web/npm-debug.log
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Zeppelin ........................................... SUCCESS [  2.527 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Interpreter .............................. SUCCESS [  6.355 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Zengine .................................. SUCCESS [  3.253 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Display system apis ...................... SUCCESS [  9.241 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark dependencies ....................... SUCCESS [ 16.473 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark .................................... SUCCESS [ 13.479 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Markdown interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [  0.270 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Angular interpreter ...................... SUCCESS [  0.162 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Shell interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  0.211 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Livy interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [  2.485 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: HBase interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  1.742 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Pig Interpreter ................... SUCCESS [  1.367 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: PostgreSQL interpreter ................... SUCCESS [  0.294 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: JDBC interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [  0.565 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: File System Interpreters ................. SUCCESS [  0.514 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Flink .................................... SUCCESS [  3.358 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Ignite interpreter ................ SUCCESS [  0.367 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Kylin interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  0.218 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Python interpreter ....................... SUCCESS [  0.252 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Lens interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [  1.496 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Cassandra interpreter ............. SUCCESS [ 29.842 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Elasticsearch interpreter ................ SUCCESS [  1.322 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: BigQuery interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [  0.389 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Alluxio interpreter ...................... SUCCESS [  1.106 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Scio ..................................... SUCCESS [ 23.182 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: web Application .......................... FAILURE [  8.124 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Server ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:09 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-28T18:16:15-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 524M/2992M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:npm (npm build) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'npm run build' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :zeppelin-web
```

Several Versions on my installations :

```
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.7
java version "1.7.0_111"
Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.4.7
git version 1.9.1
nodejs - v7.2.0
npm - 3.10.9
Apache Maven 3.3.9 
Spark 1.3.0
```

I tried lot of ways to solve this issues but no luck. Can anybody please let me out to solve this issue and run the build successfully. I really appreciate your responses and time.

**Edit**

my npm install in zeppelin-web gives below output:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.7.0: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN prefer global jsonlint@1.6.2 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global jshint@2.8.0 should be installed with -g
npm WARN lifecycle zeppelin-web@0.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) zeppelin-web@0.0.0 bower install --silent /home/zeppelin/incubator-zeppelin/zeppelin-web
zeppelin-web@0.0.0 /home/zeppelin/incubator-zeppelin/zeppelin-web
```

I haven't copied the tree here because it's too long to copy here. Thanks.

Comment: incubator-zeppelin? Why you don't use the latest version of Zeppelin and Spark?

Comment: What do you mean? I have to install it with my current hadoop.

Comment: incubator-zeppelin shall be before 0.5.6, now zeppelin is in 0.6.2. Spark 1.4 is also pretty old, latest version is 2.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem lies in the fact that zeppelin build has been updated to v0.6.2
Please add this after you clone your incubator:

1. git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin.git
2. cd incubator-zeppelin
3. git checkout c928f9a46ecacebc868d6dc10a95c02f9018a18e
4. cd ../

Maven will use zeppelin build 0.6.1 and it should finish without any error.

Comment: in which path of directory i do the git clone ?

Comment: If you use pegasus the file to modify is:
pegasus/install/zeppelin/install_zeppelin.sh

Comment: thanks man it worked for me. I have presentation tomorrow and you saved me. Appreciate your response.

Comment: i did not understand "If you use pegasus the file to modify is: pegasus/install/zeppelin/install_zeppelin.sh" this though ! can you explain more on this ?

Comment: you're welcome! This problem bothered me for past few days.

Sorry, I assumed you're using project pegasus to install your environment, because your problems were exactly the same as mine. Maybe this solution will help more people then.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever i'm getting fail about web application, I used to follow procedure.

1. `cd zeppelin-web` dir
2. remove node_modules dir
3. type `npm install`

and If you want to build Zeppelin with CDH, you should add `-Pvendor-repo` option in your build command.

You can see some Build command examples in [here](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/install/build.html#build-command-examples)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this and it's still giving me the same error. I executed the same command mentioned in the link you gave for CDH but no luck. How could i troubleshoot in other way ? Appreciate your reply.

Comment: Could you also remove the `zeppelin-web/bower_components/` before `npm install`?

Comment: i don't find the bower_components in zeppelin-web !!

Comment: Could you upgrade `node` version?

Comment: FYI My `node` version is `v5.9.1` and `npm` version is `3.7.3`, and Could you attache the all outputs of `npm install` ?

Comment: Do you thing the nodejs - v7.2.0 and npm - 3.10.9 won't work ?

Comment: Also, I am attaching the output of npm install in the main post if could look at it.

Comment: `v7.2.0` might doesn't work properly, could you downgrade to `v-6.x` or `v-5.x` it?

Comment: i can give a try but did you see the output of npm install command ? What do you think ?

Comment: It seems that the output of `npm install` command doesn't give much informations.