# build fails while installing zeppelin

Tags: maven, npm, apache-zeppelin

getting this error while installing zeppelin

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:npm (npm build) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'npm run build' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]
```

i am using below command to setup zeppelin

```
mvn clean package -Pcassandra-spark-1.5 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -Phadoop-2.6 -DskipTests
```

my maven version details are

```
    Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T08:41:47-08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-31-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

i am stuck here since more than a day.upgraded maven ,used clean install instead of clean package , upgraded npm, still getting same error.i am using 
 `npm version: 3.10.9` .

EDIT:
By running `npm run build` in zeppelin-web i am getting following error

```
    npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! zeppelin-web@0.0.0 build: `grunt build`
npm ERR! Exit status 3
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the zeppelin-web@0.0.0 build script 'grunt build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the zeppelin-web package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     grunt build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs zeppelin-web
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls zeppelin-web
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/zeppelin/zeppelin-web/npm-debug.log
```

EDIT2:
Solved it using `incubator-zeppelin` instead of `git clone https://github.com/apache/zeppelin.git`
Thnaks

Any help ll be appreciated!!

Comment: Here's my solution to the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855207/getting-error-while-building-the-apache-zeppelin/40892261#40892261

Comment: followed the same link ! Thanks @Jarek

Answer (score 0):

Which version\revision of Apache Zeppelin are you building?

There has been a bug resolved in frontend build at [recent master](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/1725) as well as 0.6-branch, so please make sure you are using latest sources.

The best way to get verbose output for frontend build is to do `npm run build` in `zeppelin-web` manually and update the post with npm build logs.

Comment: Hi! i updated the question with npm run build o/p and i tried modifying resolution filed provided in that link. but same error.. @bzz

Comment: And is there anything in error log in /root/zeppelin/zeppelin-web/npm-debug.log  ?